# Spring MVC : How managing to get a java object from a GET request?

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters, getmethod

I am trying to use SpringMVC to handle a form but now I am stuck and I'm here to ask for your help.

When the user submit the form, my controller returns the jsp result page and the user can check what he filled in. In that result page I have 2 buttons, one to send definitively the form and one to modify it.

Here my problem : when I click on modify all the fields of the form are again empty and I would like to keep the value filled by the user.

My controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/adhesion" )
public class FormController {

//Send the form
    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String getFormulaire( @RequestParam( value = "user", required = false ) T_demande_adhesion User, Map<String, Object> model ) {
        System.out.println( "user" + User ); //Null everytime
        model.put( "user", User );
        System.out.println( "Envoi formulaire !" );
        return "formulaireAdhesion";
    }

//Handle the form
    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String gestionAdhesion( @ModelAttribute( "formAdhesion" ) @Valid T_demande_adhesion user, BindingResult erreurForm, Map<String, Object> model )
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        final String CHEMIN_DOC_APP = "C:/DocumentsApp/";
        // Form JSP page
        final String FORMULAIRE_ADHESION = "formulaireAdhesion";
        // Result page
        final String AFFICHER_RESULT = "afficherResult";

        // Objet de validation du formulaire    
        ValidationDmdAdhesion demandeAdhesion = new ValidationDmdAdhesion();

//Return AFFICHER_RESULT or FORMULAIRE_ADHESION
        String resultat = demandeAdhesion.validationUser( user, erreurForm, model, FORMULAIRE_ADHESION, AFFICHER_RESULT, CHEMIN_DOC_APP  );

        //putting the object to the request
        model.put( "user", user );

        return resultat;

    }
}
```

In JSP side I added the parameter 'User' in the request : 
'

```
<input type="button" value="Modifier" onclick="document.location.href='<c:url value="adhesion?user=${user}"/>';" class="boutonAdhesion" />
```

'
But this send me a string and the url is :

```
/adhesion?user=com.user.entities.T_demande_adhesion@1dfe8158
```

When the user clicks on modifiy button (which is in the result page), I would like to get this object `@ModelAttribute( "formAdhesion" ) @Valid T_demande_adhesion user` on the GET request to fill in the form, in purpose to avoid the user to put again the same informations.
Any help ?

An extract from the form :

`<label for="nom">Nom <span class="requis">*</span></label><input type="text" id="nom" name="identite.nom"  value="<c:out value ="${user.identite.nom}"/>" size="35" maxlength="30"  />
<spring-ext:errors path="identite.nom" class="erreur" firstErrorOnly="true"/>`

It's here : `value="<c:out value ="${user.identite.nom}"/>`  that I want to get the value of `nom`.

Sorry for the English.

Frenchy.

Comment: I think your `input` tag's `onclick` attribute terminates prematurely.

I think it ends here: `onclick="document.location.href='<c:url value="`

You should escape the nested quotes, using `\"`.

Comment: I think `onclick` needs to be escaped like this:
`onclick="document.location.href='<c:url value=\"adhesion?user=${user}\"/>';"`

Comment: It cannot work if I put the "\" just after `value=`

Answer (score 0):

> When I click on modify all the fields of the form are again empty and
>   I would like to keep the value filled by the user

Because the form data is already available on the page at client side, there is no meaning of submitting the form again to the server & show the same data, which is an unnecessary round trip from the client to the server i.e.,

To keep the data on the form, do NOT to submit the form to the server/controller itself.

> How can I check the validation of the information filled in without
>   submit the form? How can I display them in my result page?

There is no need to validate the data that the user is anyhow going to modify. So, the validation of the form will be done **only after the user completes the modifications and clicks on Submit**. Once the validations are successful/failed, your can show the result on the results page.

Comment: It's a good suggestion but how can I check the validation of the information filled in without submit the form? How can I display them in my result page?

Comment: You can look at y answer above.

Comment: It's a good idea, but the problem will be the same if the validation sends an error I will need to redirect the user to the form.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I didn't find another way than using @SessionAttributes. In this point off my application I didn't to use a session but it seems that there isn't another way.